# Python: Get volume serial number from lnk file?

Tags: python, volume, serial-number

I have a lnk file (shortcut file). I have used a tool called Windows LNK Parsing Utility (lp) to find out the volume serial number that the original file was sitting on. So I wanted to create a script in python that does the same.

I found that the win32api module should help, so here is my code:

```
import win32api, win32con, win32security # win32api main mod, other modules to get SID

path = ('C:\Users\Si\Desktop\Files\Shortcut to Pictures.lnk')

print win32api.GetVolumeInformation(path)


Error says:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Si\Desktop\Files\test.py", line 3, in <module> pywintypes.error: (123, 'GetVolumeInformation', 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.')
```

Is there another (perhaps better?) way of accomplishing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation

```
tuple = GetVolumeInformation(path)

Returns information about a file system and colume whose root directory is specified.
```

May be

```
win32api.GetVolumeInformation('C:\\')
```

Comment: It works with 'C:\\' but not with a file such as "C:\\file.txt"

Comment: Extract root from file path and use it instead of full path.